# Elementor Popup shows bottom content first not start from the top

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor

I added a popup to my website when click on it, it opens at the bottom means it showing bottom content first there is a hyperlink at the bottom of the popup when I remove the hyperlink the problem solved. but I need that hyperlink is this any way to fix this problem

Help me if you know anything about it...

I want that popup opens at the top

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the Popup settings there is an item:

"**Accessible navigation.
Allow keyboard tab navigation for accessibility**"

It is enabled by default - **disable** it and it will **work**!

[image: Accessible Navigation]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this.

1. Add an Anchor immediately above or below the first item at the top of your popup (I inserted the anchor just below my popup's Title)
2. Give the Anchor an ID (i.e. popup_name)
3. Link the first item to the anchor (i.e. #popup_name)

This resolved the issue for me, and the popup opens to display the top content first. I hope it works for you too!